# Почему рыжий таракан — прусак?

Tags: этимология

Задумался тут о народных названиях животных. Интересно, а почему рыжий таракан — прусак? Если от слова "Пруссия", тогда почему одно С? И правда ли (не помню уже, где такое слышал), что сами немцы таких тараканов называли, наоборот, "русак"?
Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В XVIII веке Россия воевала с Пруссией на её территории и одержала ряд побед. Однако это обернулось массовым переселением европейских тараканов в Петербург, Москву и многие другие города. Дело в том, что русские солдаты, само собой разумеется, бывали в прусских кабаках и харчевнях, где эти насекомые водились в изобилии,да и  мародерствовали: военные трофеи, всякий скарб домой везли. Вместе с ним и этих тараканов. Они забирались в походные солдатские ранцы, да так и попали в итоге в Россию, где прежде их не было совсем. Понятно, что иноземных гостей сразу же окрестили «прусаками».Черные "приехали" из Турции в XVIII веке.  Во Франции рыжих тараканов тоже прусаками зовут. На востоке Германии их называют  русаками. На севере Германии рыжие тараканы - швабы, а на западе - французы.

http://allforchildren.ru/why/why4.php

Comment: А одно С -как и в разговорных оперетка, пятитонка,как в словах финка, будёновка - бывают исключения в русском языке. и в большом количестве.

Answer (score 2):

По другой версии хитиновые надкрылья рыжих тараканов по форме напоминают раздвонные сзади мундиры прусских солдат (помните моду XVIII века?) 
насчет путешествия в солдатских ранцах... Честно говоря - сомневаюсь. 
Таракан комфорт любит. Скорее уж офицеры завезли в своих походных сундуках с перинами.

Comment: Ого! Так вот, кто нам их подсунул!))) А в России, выходит, тараканов раньше не было?

Comment: Были. Но больше - черные. А рыжие - другой вид (или подвид - не силен): поменьше размером и не такой наглый.

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё версия из материала Л.Вяткина ("Самые знаменитые тайны России"). Во время Наполеоновских войн генерал-майор прусской армии Гебхард Лебрехт Блюхер изобрёл собственную тактику для борьбы с превосходящими силами Наполеона: в бою вылезать из всех щелей, а после боя, (как правило, проигранного), собираться в заранее оговоренном месте, эдакий большой сбор.
Наполеона она страшно злила, и он презрительно назвал эту тактику "тараканьей", а рыжих тараканов "пруссаками".